# An English language learner better not ask in this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, duplicates, question-closure, ell

An English language learner better not ask in this site?

I asked [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159116/this-box-of-matches-is-empty) and it had been closed as off-topic(it was reopened).
Some members seem to have an opinion that a learner better not ask here(see the comments of the above mentioned thread).
I would like to know your opinions.

Comment: Please don't put words in other people's mouths. I don't think anyone here has said that English language learners shouldn't post on [main]. Several people have noted that certain **questions** are off-topic (like FumbleFingers and I have said, in the linked question).

Comment: Please also see the “Related” questions at the right. A few of them also deal with issues related to English language learners.

Comment: All that said, if you have questions about learning or teaching English, they are probably a better fit for [ell.se].

Comment: @BraddSzonye The two questions are related but different.
Why do you think they are the same?

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate, but it deals with the same topic in relation to the same question on [main], and the answers to it are applicable to this one. When you have questions about learning and teaching English, you should probably post them to [ell.se] instead of here. When you have questions about [main] **within the scope given in the help center,** you should ask here. Several people have given you this same advice now. If it doesn't answer your meta question, you should **edit** the previous question to explain why and how you need more information.

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*I don't think anyone here has said that English language learners shouldn't post on English Language & Usage.*]
Nobody said that, but some people seem to have an opinion that a learner better not ask here.

Comment: You are referring to FumbleFingers, yes? I'm almost certain that he doesn't believe that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're having difficulty with, so I can't elaborate. (Also, when I have elaborated in the past, you have responded simply by repeating the same questions, so it does not appear that elaboration is effective or worth my time.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*You are referring to FumbleFingers, yes?*]
It doesn't matter who I am referring to.
It doesn't even matter whether I am reffering to an existing person.
I am just asking whether an English language learner better not ask in this site.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Re:FumbleFingers - "all he needs to know is that he is a learner, and thus it's very likely that his question will be a better fit on the learners' site" - 'shouldn't' is not the same as 'likely' but it's translating the same to ivanhoe.

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're having difficulty with, so I can't elaborate.*]
The two questions are related but they are not even similar.
Why do you think they are similar?

Comment: ivanhoescott: You keep repeating the same questions to different people, with trivial variation between them, without ever showing any sign that you comprehend even **part** of what we are trying to tell you. You have resisted every piece of advice people have given to you, like visiting the help center or posting questions on [ell.se]. That's frankly aggravating, and hardly distinguishable from trolling. Please **stop** repeating the same questions and spend some time taking advantage of the resources that people have been trying to give you.

Comment: @Mitch I think "shouldn't" and "better not" are different.
Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mitch Yep, I saw that too. Honestly, I can't tell whether anything is getting through to ivanhoescott at all, because he never clarifies or confirms or adds new information, but instead just keeps repeating questions, most of them leading, which is infuriating, especially when a “you've got mail” flag keeps popping up in my SE mailbox.

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*You keep repeating the same questions to different people*]
What's wrong with that if that is the case?
Different people may have different opinions.

Comment: ivanhoescott: The SE comment system is not designed for having extended discussions in comments. It's very disruptive, as I noted in my comment to Mitch. If you don't understand what people are saying in comments, please discuss it in ELU chat rather than asking for the same clarification repeatedly.

Comment: Also, as I have mentioned before, StackExchange **strongly** expects you to help yourself, and to get more information by **improving** your questions, not just repeating them and asking more people. **This is not a discussion forum,** and **opinion polling in particular is strongly discouraged.** Which is why you should be editing your earlier question with more information, rather than posting another one and asking over and over what's wrong with that.

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*The SE comment system is not designed for having extended discussions in comments.*]
I know. That's why I opened this meta thread.

Comment: But still you keep using comments like they were a chat system. **If you want to start a dialogue, please use the chat room:** that's what it's for. Meta does allow some limited discussion, but it's still aimed mainly at the question-and-answer format. And on meta we still expect you to follow general SE practices like improving questions based on feedback, rather that posting near-duplicates.

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*This is not a discussion forum, and opinion polling in particular is strongly discouraged.*]
The main site is not a discussion forum, but the meta site is exactly for discussions for meta issues. And this is a thread asking a meta question.

Comment: The fact that you need to quote context in your comments to keep track of everyone and everything you are replying to is a good sign that you should be having this discussion in chat, **not** in comments. The comment system is not designed for this.

Comment: @BraddSzonye [*The fact that you need to quote context in your comments to keep track of everyone and everything you are replying to is a good sign that you should be having this discussion in chat, not in comments. The comment system is not designed for this.*]
Then what is the purpose of the "discussion" tag in the meta?

Comment: *Discussion* has a specific meaning here that you can see by hovering over or clicking on the tag: “The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.” It is not for extensive, back-and-forth dialogue or for picking nits. It's simply an extension of the question-and-answer format that is more permissive about answers that are largely opinion-based.

Comment: If you have further questions about this, please visit ELU chat; people there will be happy to help you. Meanwhile, I strongly recommend not repeating the same behavior that previously led to flagging and suspension.

Answer (score 6):

To directly answer your question:

There is a second site, **English Language Learners (ELL)**.  It is designed for people who are trying to learn English when it is not their primary language.

**English Langugage & Usage (ELU)**  assumes that the users already have a fairly advanced degree of knowledge of the English language and are asking more complicated questions.  (As a general rule: On-topic questions would likely be at least a mild challenge to a native speaker.)

When we vote to close a question here, it is because it doesn't specifically fit the profile of a question on this site.

The most common reason for closure is that the answer would a) be readily apparent to a native speaker, b) would be easily found within a general reference that is readily available.  We call this closure reason General Reference.  *The majority of questions that are asked by non-native speakers fall into this category; many of these questions would likely be more welcome on ELL.*

There are some, however, that have clearly done their research and are asking for clarification of certain nuances that might not be readily apparent from those general references.  Those questions are typically welcome on ELU.  The key difference is:  **the general reference research has been done PRIOR to posting the question.**

So, to make my point clearer:  We have a thriving community of non-native English speakers here.  And, many of them are our finest contributors.  But, they already possess a significant proficiency in the English language.  Some, in fact, are more knowledgable than a native speaker with regard to grammatical usage, and other fine points.

There is no stigma to being asked to post on ELL instead of ELU.  That is the entire reason ELL exists, to help people who are trying to learn to speak English at most levels.  If you post a question and it gets closed, then please read the comments explaining why the close votes were applied.  If many of them recommend posting on ELL, then consider reposting it there.  You will likely get a better and more complete answer there.

Comment: Well said. *It would be better to ask this on ELL* **≠** *An English language learner better not ask at ELU*. In fact, a pointer to ELL should be regarded as helpful and friendly advice; more often than not, that's the spirit with which it was written. It's **not** an exhortation to scram.

Comment: @J.R. Well said, to you too, sir!

Comment: [*But, they already possess a significant proficiency in the English language.*]
What if a learner doesn't have such a proficiency?
Do you advise him to ask whatever questions in another site?

Comment: @ivanhoescott I usually recommend that they ask on English Language Learners.

Comment: @DavidM [*I usually recommend that they ask on English Language Learners.*]
Even if his question might be interesting for many members of this site?

Comment: @ivanhoescott Can you give an example?

Comment: @ivanhoescott This isn't e-mail; it isn't necessary to quote every message you're responding to, and it's somewhat distracting. (If the conversation is convoluted enough that you need to quote context, then it's too chatty for comments.)

Comment: @DavidM [*Can you give an example?*]
If you don't find [my question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159116/this-box-of-matches-is-empty) interesting,
I could have asked [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) for example.

Answer (score 4):

I think that every site under the StackExchange umbrella has had a question on its meta site making a similar point.  The point being that new users are not made welcome.

In all cases the answer is similar.  The sites have different expectations of their users than a simple forum site would.

This has the disadvantage that it can appear unwelcoming to new users who fall foul of the standards required.  The flags and comments received may appear brusque and unwelcoming.

This is outweighed by major advantages.  These sites form a repository of useful information that can be read easily.  The Q&A format leads a reader to information without having to trawl through the drivel of a forum's stream of conciousness.  It is very often not necessary to post a question as the answer can be found simply.  Of course, not all other forums are bad and these SE sites are not perfect.

The sites are not as unwelcoming as you may at first think.  Please continue to use the site, all are welcome here.  Just please take a moment to understand what there is on offer and what you can offer in return.